# Eclipse RCP authentication

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I would like to know how to implement authentication in Eclipse RCP. I have started an app and I have two views, one for admin and one for a regular user. At startup I want to show the login dialog and depending of type of user to show a view. Can anyone tell me which is the best way to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'll suggest you that create a single view for both admin and regular user . Just create different widgets for the admin and regular user . Before creating the view just hook the Login Dialog and on the basis of authentication from the login dialog load the widgets in the view .

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to do this :-)

I usually recommend using activities as these are completely independent of the code for the view, perspectives, commands, etc.

See [this blog entry](http://tonnymadsen.blogspot.dk/2007/06/using-activities-for-user-management.html) on how to set-up the activities.